# Spring boot app cant connect to mysql db - docker-compose

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, hibernate, docker-compose

I tried many ways and every time the application runs in the container I get such errors:

```
WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
```

my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: configs_mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: scrap
      MYSQL_USER: scrap
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: scrap
      MYSQL_DATABASE: configs
    networks:
      - my_network
  web:
    build: .
    image: scrapyconfigmanager_web
    ports:
      - "8181:8181"
    networks:
      - my_network
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
# Copy source code to temporary building location
WORKDIR /source_code
COPY . .
RUN ./gradlew bootJar

WORKDIR /scrapy
RUN cp /source_code/build/libs/ScrapyConfigManager-1.0.jar .

EXPOSE 8181
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","ScrapyConfigManager-1.0.jar"]
```

my hibernate.cfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://configs_mysql:3306/configs</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">scrap</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">scrap</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
        <mapping class="org.scrapeusz.model.OlxCar" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Both containers start up, but after a while the spring container stops.
Below I paste part of the code from the terminal after the "docker-compose up" command:

```
Creating configs_mysql ... done
Creating scrapyconfigmanager_web_1 ... done
Attaching to configs_mysql, scrapyconfigmanager_web_1
configs_mysql | 2022-07-21 10:34:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1.el8 started.
configs_mysql | 2022-07-21 10:34:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
configs_mysql | 2022-07-21 10:34:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1.el8 started.
configs_mysql | 2022-07-21 10:34:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
configs_mysql | 2022-07-21T10:34:49.504138Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) initializing of server in progress as process 42
configs_mysql | 2022-07-21T10:34:49.515175Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
configs_mysql | 2022-07-21T10:34:49.795876Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
web_1    | 
web_1    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
web_1    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
web_1    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
web_1    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
web_1    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
web_1    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
web_1    |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.6)
web_1    | 
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:50.905  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.scrapeusz.ScrapyConfigManager        : Starting ScrapyConfigManager using Java 11.0.15 on 71d7d66bbd3b with PID 1 (/scrapy/ScrapyConfigManager-1.0.jar started by root in /scrapy)
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:50.910  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.scrapeusz.ScrapyConfigManager        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
configs_mysql | 2022-07-21T10:34:51.393524Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:52.239  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:52.255  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:52.255  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:52.364  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:52.364  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1388 ms
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:52.577  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.0.0.Final
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:53.269  WARN 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:53.275  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:53.275  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:mysql://configs_mysql:3306/configs]
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:53.275  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=scrap}
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:53.276  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:53.279  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
web_1    | 2022-07-21 10:34:53.407  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
web_1    | 
web_1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
web_1    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar!/:6.0.0.Final]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `hibernate.cfg` file.

You are referring container name as database host in that config file.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://configs_mysql:3306/configs</property>
```

**configs_mysql** is your container name but it not your DB host in the docker world. Remember communication between the docker containers inside the docker compose network will happen through service name.

For Database service you defined **mysql** as your service name.

Change the **hibernate.connection.url** to below

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/configs</property>
```

Refer: [Docker compose with multiple services (app and DB)](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/#run-the-application-stack)